# How to vertical-align table cell content with image using bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a little bit complicated table which looks like this

```
<tr class='row-eq-height'>
<td><img/><div with text></td>
<td><img/><div with text></td>
<td><img/><div with text></td>
</tr>
```

But images have different size so i added `max-width: 300px` to them.
And now it looks like

```
image      | image
text       | different text
some space | different space
```

So I want to stick my div with text to the bottom. I've already tried vertical align but it doesn't help at all.
Finally table should look like that

```
image      | image
some space | different space
text       | different text
```

jsfiddle [example](https://jsfiddle.net/4wnrq0kq/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `flexbox` and set `display: flex` on `tr` to make each `td` equal height and `justify-content: space-between` with `flex-direction: column` on `td` to position image on top and text on bottom.

```css
tr {
  display: flex;
}
td {
  max-width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class='row-eq-height'>
  <td><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150"><div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div></td>
  <td><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150"><div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro praesentium repudiandae odit sint iure deleniti!</div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I've tried to use your style, but it doesn't move my div to the bottom

Comment: Can you create fiddle with your code.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/4wnrq0kq/

Comment: It should be inline-flex, not flex-inline, finally found it. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

**Working example** http://jsfiddle.net/yg0Lhhju/1/

```
.parent {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
}

.child {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: you could give some border or background-color to that container to better appreciate it is working

Comment: It doesn't work

Comment: @Bhupinderkumar this is how it looks for me: https://i.imgsafe.org/c6fd355b0f.png